# Receiving a "Unknown column 'users_permissions.user_id' in 'where clause'" error in SQL statement

Tags: sql

Not quite sure why I'm getting this error as these columns exist.

```
SELECT (SELECT first_name
        FROM users u
        WHERE u.assistant_id=users_permissions.user_id LIMIT 1) as Name, AVG(duration)
FROM aircalls a
WHERE assistant_id !='NULL' AND status='Call Connected'
AND DATE_FORMAT(a.created_at,'%Y')='2019' 
GROUP BY assistant_id
```

Comment: I don't see `users_permissions` table anywhere in the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you missed   the table  users_permissions in your subquery

```
    SELECT (
        SELECT first_name
        FROM users u
        INNER JOIN users_permissions ON  u.assistant_id=users_permissions.user_id 
        LIMIT 1) as Name, AVG(duration)
    FROM aircalls a
    WHERE assistant_id !='NULL' AND status='Call Connected'
    AND DATE_FORMAT(a.created_at,'%Y')='2019' 
    GROUP BY NAME
```

Comment: Spot on. Thank you for the clarification @scaisEdge

Answer (score 0):

You must add the table 'users_permission' to the subquery - FROM clause

```
 SELECT (SELECT first_name
            FROM users u, users_permission
            WHERE u.assistant_id=users_permissions.user_id LIMIT 1) as Name, AVG(duration)
    FROM aircalls a
    WHERE assistant_id !='NULL' AND status='Call Connected'
    AND DATE_FORMAT(a.created_at,'%Y')='2019' 
    GROUP BY assistant_id
```

Comment: Use proper `JOIN`.  It's been around for over 25 years.

Comment: @Eric Thank's for the heads up. I have NOT been around databases for over 25 years like "JOIN", so I'm still learning. I'll give it a try.